# Creating dynamic pages for content-type/taxonomy-term

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms, 6

I have two content types:

- news
- review

I have a taxonomy vocabulary attached to them with following terms

- tech
- entertainment
- other
- (More may come)

I need to have a listing of these contents in following format:

- tech/news (or news/tech)
- tech/reviews (or reviews/tech)
- other/news (or other/news)
- other/reviews (or other/reviews)

..and so on.

I could create a page for every required URL pattern and create a separate view for each. But is there any dynamic way to do it in views?

At least, can I add a drop down filter for content type on term pages?

I'm using Drupal 6.

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: why don't you use one vocabulary?

Comment: It's one vocabulary only with multiple terms in it. and for content types i need multiple content types to theme differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

1. Create one page view and give him a path like: `%/%`
2. Add contextual filters
3. Create a module
4. Implement hook_menu.

..

```
function test_menu() {
  $items['test/%term_name/%node_type_name'] = array(
    'title' => 'My test page',
    'page callback' => 'test_page_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page arguments' => array(1,2),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function test_page_callback($term_name, $node_type_name) {

  /**
   * here we are getting arguments from _to_arg() functions and processing them to
   * get $tid and $SECOND_ARGUMENT
   */

  return render(views_embed_view('test_veiw', 'test_display', $tid, $SECOND_ARGUMENT));
}

function term_name_to_arg() {
  // return term_name as argument
}


function node_type_name_to_arg() {
// return node_type_name as argument
}
```